# commuicate ' User' model between two microservices

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, microservices, communication

**hello everyone i'm new to microservice's architecture** ,
so i have a miscroservice which every entity is linked to the 'user' entity , but the problem is that the
'user' entity is in another microservice , is there any solution ?

1. I don't know where to user the  @onetomany relation if i don't have the two entities in the same microservice)
2. i can't combine the two microservices together.

what about domain model layer ? is it the best solution to user another microservice's data ?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Cant you pass it as a secure jwt token which contains users data so its accessible in other micro service? Another approach is store it as a thread local object.

Answer (score 0):

First answering your questions

1 - I don't know where to user the @onetomany relation if i don't have the two entities in the same microservice)

2 - i can't combine the two microservices together.

--> you can combine 2 services into one (provided considering the load of service)

If the load on your service is big - then

You can utilize something like shared database service for multiple microservices

Go through this blog - it talks about few patterns you can utilize.

http://microservices.io/patterns/data/database-per-service.html.

Also go through this question,  it will give you some more undersntading

[Microservices: how to handle foreign key relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44870461/microservices-how-to-handle-foreign-key-relationships)